# HTML POST form in Django giving TypeError when submitted

Tags: python, django

I'm trying get user input from a HTML form and use that value to populate a ChartJS graph in my Django app called DisplayData which has a template called Display.html. I have the following form in my project.

Display.html

```
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="textfield">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

In my views file, I have the following code to get the data from this form:

views.py

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    display_id = 0

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        display_id = self.request.POST.get("textfield")

        try:
           display_id = int(display_id) 
        except ValueError: 
           display_id = 2

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        display_id = self.request.GET.get("textfield") 

        all_entries = models.Entries.objects.all().filter(parent=display_id) #change to input from text box via display_id
        all_id = models.Entries.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
        all_measurables = models.Measurables.objects.all().filter(user_id=request.user.id) #change to current user



        all_times = [m.timestamp for m in all_entries]

        all_data = []
        for m in all_entries:
            data = m.data
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            value = json_data['value']
            all_data.append(value)


        data = {
            "labels": all_times,
            "default": all_data,
        }   
        return Response(data)
```

My urls are set up as follows.

urls.py

```
from .views import get_data, ChartData

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.DisplayView, name='DisplayView'),
    url(r'^api/data/$', views.get_data, name='api-data'),
    url(r'^display/api/chart/data/$', views.ChartData.as_view()),
    url(r'^logs/', views.LogDisplay, name='Display-Logs'),
]
```

When I go into the form in the page and type in a number and hit submit, in my console I get the following error:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: self.request.GET.get("textfield")

Comment: @Thameem.  If the form method is `post`.How data will get in `request.GET` ?

Comment: @itzmeontv he is changing his question . frequently ..his question is not stable.. i gave answer for his previous version..little before he trying to access Post request in get method . so point this to him

Comment: I didn't change my question. I am still not getting the number value from the form, I am getting None after making all the changes. I need to get the number from the form into my get method to use it for all_entries = models.Entries.objects.all().filter(parent=display_id)

Comment: @FlameDra "I didn't change my question". Are you sure of that? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43603057/revisions

Comment: @FlameDra you are not return anything in your post method

Comment: Should I return(display_id) ?

Comment: @FlameDra whatever the data you want in frontend.

Comment: I returned that. In my def get(...) I tried to do: display_id = self.request.POST.get("textfield")

But it is None. Shouldn't it be the value being returned by def post(...), which is the form input, which is 2 (what I am entering) ?

Comment: @FlameDra get method is to handle get request and post method is to handle post method.here your request is a post. so it wont work with get method. so please replace you get method with post and try ... you please delete that get method pass all your code inside your post method

Comment: So how can I use the number I get to generate my graph? I need to pass that number into :  all_entries = models.Entries.objects.all().filter(parent=OVERHERE) which happens to be inside my get method.

Comment: @FlameDra you write all those code inside your post method and try atlease once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142573/discussion-between-thameem-and-flamedra).

Answer (score 1):

> Using the APIView class is pretty much the same as using a regular View class, as usual, the incoming request is dispatched to an appropriate handler method such as .get() or .post()

If you doing a `POST` request.You have to do

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    #rest of code
```

Comment: What goes into rest of code? ` display_id = request.POST.get("textfield") #get data from form
        display_id = int(display_id)` ? How do I access the variable display_id in my class ChartData(APIView) then?

Comment: check by printing `request.data` or `request.POST`.So `display_id = request.data.get("textfield")`

Comment: so when inside def get(...), request.data will contain whatever I input into my form?

Comment: Yes. It will be there. Not `get` but `post`

Comment: Try by `print request.data` on top of the `try except` .Post it here

Comment: It doesn't print anything:

[25/Apr/2017 02:55:09] "GET /display/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6116
[25/Apr/2017 02:55:09] "GET /display/display/api/chart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26
[25/Apr/2017 02:55:14] "POST /display/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6116
[25/Apr/2017 02:55:15] "GET /display/display/api/chart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26

Comment: In html form where is action url ? If not which url where form is loaded ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, what does action url mean?

Comment: HTML form has to submit form data to some url.

Comment: And then I can use it in my get method to generate my graph? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 display_id = request.POST.get("textfield")
```

error with this line. you are missing `self`. here it is returning NoneType. And change your method to `post`

```
def post(self, request, format=None):


 display_id = self.request.POST.get("textfield")

try:
       display_id = int(display_id) 
except ValueError: 
       display_id = "here you give default value"
```

you got this error because you are trying to pass non-integer value as a string

Comment: I changed it and now I get: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' @Thameem

Comment: textfield contains string or number:
try:
display_id = request.POST.get("textfield") #get data from form
        display_id = int(display_id)
except ValueError:
display_id = "here you give default value"
you got this error because you are trying to pass non-integer value as a string

Comment: @Thameem he has a request in the parameters in the method declaration. Adding self isn't the best way I think. Second, I agree with the ``texfield contains string or number`` argument but instead adding a ``try: .. except ValueError`` he can just change the HTML to ``<input type="number" name="someid" />``

Comment: I'm typing the number 2 into the form, and then clicking submit. Shouldn't I get a string "2" which is converted to an int 2 with the casting?

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński here is missing self.request. i just point that. He can use type="number". thats is a good solution.

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński I changed the input of the form to number as you suggested, and also added the try/except as Thameem suggested. Now when I input the number 2 into the form and click Submit, I get: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: def get(self, request, format=None): change to def post

Comment: exactly as @Thameem suggested

Comment: How will I access the display_id variable in my def get then? I get NameError: name 'display_id' is not defined

Comment: you need to define a get method just like post.